# The last rule of pypsa-earth "solve_network" does not work properly

Tags: python, pycharm, pypsa

I want to use pypsa-earth in China, where rules are typically strictly enforced. However, I am encountering difficulties with the final step of the process, which consistently shows a " returned non-zero exit status 1" in the terminal, as shown below.

```
(ERROR:snakemake.logging: Error in rule solve_network:

    jobid: 1
    input: networks/elec_s_10_ec_lcopt_Co2L-3H.nc
    output: results/networks/elec_s_10_ec_lcopt_Co2L-3H.nc
    log: logs\solve_network\elec_s_10_ec_lcopt_Co2L-3H_solver.log, logs/solve_network/elec_s_10_ec_lcopt_Co2L-3H_python.log (check log file(s) for e
rror details)

RuleException:
CalledProcessError in file D:\pypsa_earth\pypsa-earth-project\pypsa-earth\Snakefile, line 836:
Command 'D:/Anaconda3/envs/pypsa-earth/python.exe "D:\pypsa_earth\pypsa-earth-project\pypsa-earth\.snakemake\shadow\tmp5_0pdd_u\.snakemake\scripts\t
mp06cl0g79.solve_network.py"' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "D:\pypsa_earth\pypsa-earth-project\pypsa-earth\Snakefile", line 836, in __rule_solve_network
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pypsa-earth\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
ERROR:snakemake.logging:RuleException:
CalledProcessError in file D:\pypsa_earth\pypsa-earth-project\pypsa-earth\Snakefile, line 836:
Command 'D:/Anaconda3/envs/pypsa-earth/python.exe "D:\pypsa_earth\pypsa-earth-project\pypsa-earth\.snakemake\shadow\tmp5_0pdd_u\.snakemake\scripts\t
mp06cl0g79.solve_network.py"' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "D:\pypsa_earth\pypsa-earth-project\pypsa-earth\Snakefile", line 836, in __rule_solve_network
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pypsa-earth\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
Shutting down, this might take some time.
WARNING:snakemake.logging:Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
ERROR:snakemake.logging:Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: .snakemake\log\2024-02-25T181828.761216.snakemake.log
WARNING:snakemake.logging:Complete log: .snakemake\log\2024-02-25T181828.761216.snakemake.log)
```

I am executing Snakemake through PyCharm, and the only changes I have made are related to adjusting the country code in the configuration file and enabling the "build_cutouts" rule.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Pypsa finishes successfully when the following rows are changed in the config file:

- `[solving]:[options]:[max_iterations] = 60000` (there isn't some big logic, that's just random big number)
- `[solving]:[options]:[nhours] = 1`  (maybe it isn't necessary).